# Kotlin coroutines cooperative cancelation explanation

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

After reading the official [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) on coroutine cancelation, If for the example I have the following code:

```
val job = scope.launch { 

    val userId = networkOperationOne()

    //check if coroutine is still active before calling operation two?

    val userDetails = networkOperationTwo(userId)
}
```

Should I check `isActive` before calling network call two?

Let's assume that `job.cancel()` was called while `networkOperationOne()` is still in progress and that I'm not calling any suspending function that automatically does the cancelation for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `networkOperationOne` and `networkOperationTwo` are suspending.

They may internally be cooperative anyway, which means you do not have to check `isActive`.

When in doubt, throw in `ensureActive()` to perform the check and act accordingly.
In this case, the conditional check is negligible compared to the network request so add one in.